# Formatting input from excel to mysql using command line client

Tags: mysql, excel, csv

I want to import data from excel to a mysql database using the command line client.
This is an example of how my csv-file is built:

```
Name 1 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
Name 2 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
Name 3 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
```

I'm using the code:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'path to file.csv'
  INTO TABLE table_name
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

I get the "Query OK" and with this code the formatting on the table should be almost exactly as the csv-file but I get this result:

```
| NULL | NULL | NULL | 
| NULL | NULL | NULL |
| NULL | NULL | NULL |
```

What is wrong?

Comment: To make it simple try with some GUI clients like SQLyog or MySQL workbench...

Comment: @SathishD I tried with workbench but I cant even get the import to work there

Comment: What is the structure of `table_name`?

Answer (score 0):

seems u have used '|' in your csv file as delimiters instead of 
comma, try the code as

```
`LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'path to file.csv' INTO TABLE table_name FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';`
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume the following table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `table_name` (
  `name` VARCHAR(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `value1` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `value2` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `value3` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

and the file, csv-file.csv:

```
Name 1,1,2,3
Name 2,1,2,3
Name 3,1,2,3
```

when I run the statement:

```
mysql> LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/csv-file.csv'
       -> INTO TABLE `table_name`
       -> FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
       -> LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';

mysql> SELECT `name`, `value1`, `value2`, `value3`
       FROM `table_name`;
```

get the following result:

```
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| name   | value1 | value2 | value3 |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| Name 1 |      1 |      2 |      3 |
| Name 2 |      1 |      2 |      3 |
| Name 3 |      1 |      2 |      3 |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: I solved it! The problem was that my fields were terminated by ; instead of ,. I saw that when I looked at my csv-file in notepad.